# Are Cinnamon themes changing only the the panel?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, theme

Using Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon with different themes, I see that few elements are changing with the theme, while most remain unchanged, especially the general background of windows and applications, which remain grey.

**Icons and windows** decorations are changeable but **not** through the theme.

**The only thing that really changes is the panel and its applets.**

**Firefox** is not at all affected by system themes and even Firefox themes cannot change the colour too much.

**The file managers are not affected by the change of theme.** Not at all. Even the minty selection is unaffected. There is no flatness and no transparency for file manager windows and for windows in general. The grey is there to stay.

[image]

The general look is elegant but the lack of customization makes one think to the mac file manager than to a Linux environment.

While windows decorations can be changed separately, the space below them stays grey no matter the theme, so for the sake of consistency one is tempted to keep a default grey too.

---

Is this a general Cinnamon aspect or limited to Mint?

Or maybe I miss something here?

Comment: I think this is limited to Mint. I'm using Cinnamon on Fedora 20 and those things change.

Comment: @sim - I cannot say this doesn't look nice. But it's somewhere between the two: on the one hand a lot of greyish macintosh-like consistency, on the other some customization that may brake consistency before recreating it. - This will cool down my restless customizing mania.

Comment: Ah! Should've realized it was a version thing. I'm on Cinnamon 2.2.14 on Fedora 20.

Comment: @slm - 2.4 version is too unstable. i have installed it and now am trying to go back to stable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will (has) changed drastically with Cinnamon version 2.4.

The answer is that the Cinnamon themes are not limited to the panel, but Mint with Cinnamon <2.4 was hiding a lot of features of those themes.

A new way of handling the themes comes with v. 2.4. especially with the 'Controls' option. Now the normal Linux flexibility is there:

[image]

[image]

More details [here](http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2014/11/cinnamon-2-4/).

For the moment (end of November 2014) the 2.4 version (available in Linux Mint from Romeo sources) has a lot of incoherences and should be installed only for testing.

---

Version 2.4 is at the present in Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.1 Rebecca. The unstable version is very risky. I have tested it in LMC 17 Qiana  and the panel started freezing. Take care.